# comparing character always returns true

Tags: c++

Why does `hasParenthesis` always evaluate to true?

```
bool hasParenthesis = false ;
for(int i = 0; i < 255 && statement[i] != ';'; i++)
{
  if(statement[i] == '(' || statement[i] == ')')
  {
    hasParenthesis = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: you're not resetting the hasParenthesis to false every time around the loop....

Comment: and what is statement value?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity he already has break there, so once it hits the if block there is no more looping.

Comment: As an aside I think you want `&&` rather than `||` in your `for` statement.

Comment: no actually. I just want to check if the entered input by the user contains parenthesis. :)

Comment: Have you considered using `std::string` ala `my_string.find_first_of("()")`? See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

Comment: @TonyD I have :) See my answer. I assume he is already using `std::string` and not some other abomination, because the question is tagged `C++`...

Comment: @jm- please note that I edited your question, I changed the logic of your for loop to use && and not ||. If `statement`'s length was 255, and the last char was ';', then your code would attempt to read one index too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the for loop starts, set `hasParenthesis` to be false. With what you currently have, once the boolean's true, it'll always be true when the loop re-iterates. So start off the for loop logic with the boolean false.

Here's a simplified skeleton:

```
bool hasParenthesis;
for(){
    hasParenthesis = false;

    if(){
      hasParenthesis = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, @jm-. If it helped, you should mark it as answered ;) And to whoever downvoted the answer, what's wrong?

Comment: Just tick that white checkmark next to my answer :D

Answer (score 2):

> Waiter, there's an if in my loop!

Assuming `statement` is a `std::string`, you can get rid of both:

```
auto pos = statement.find_first_of(";()");
bool hasParenthesis = (pos != std::string::npos) && (statement[pos] != ';');
```